# Find Control returning null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, nullreferenceexception, findcontrol

When I try to find a control on the current page, it returns null every time and the control is right there.

HTML:

```html
<input type="radio" id="test2" value="Hello World" name="Test"/>
```

Code Behind

```html
HtmlInputRadioButton control = (HtmlInputRadioButton)Page.FindControl("test2");
            Response.Write(control.Value);
            Response.Write(control.ID);
```

Any idea why it keeps returning null??

[image]

Comment: The FindControl function is not recursive so if you have the control encapsulated in a div or table it will not find it. Try to use Master.FindControl(btnName);    More info about how to locate controls when you don t know the container can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/y81z8326(v=vs.100)

Comment: Its not in a div but I will try master

Comment: @ClaudioCorchez Didnt work for me.

Comment: Walter you could create a function to search for the control in a recursive manner. https://blog.justincarmony.com/2008/02/12/pagefindcontrol-returning-null-issues-and-solutions-within-another-control/

Comment: `FindControl` finds server controls. The one you're looking for isn't a server control. No `runat="server"`. You can make it a server control (if that fits your needs.)

Comment: @ScottHannen I added runat="server" and ithe result is the same

Comment: Is it inside the form runat=server tags? It will need to be.

Comment: Yes it is. Its a weird problem.